# Toyota 96 Ae102 Seca Corolla

Tags: central-locking

Can anyone advise, original key fob lost prior to owning car.
Used key only for years, suddenly doors quickly relock after turning key in door. Security Dash light is now on and engine is immobilized and won't start.
Has anyone encountered this issue, help with a solution please?